# Integral through $u$-substitution v. multiplying out

Tags: integration

I have the integral:

$ \int (x^2)(x^3-1)^2 \, dx $  Through $u$-substitution, I can write this is equal to $ \frac {1}{3} \int (3x^2)(x^3-1)^2 dx $  which equals $ \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{(x^3-1)^3}{3}$.

However, if rather than using $u$-substitution, I multiply within $ \int (x^2)(x^3-1)^2 \, dx $ from the beginning, I don't get the same answer. For example: $ \int (x^2)(x^3-1)^2 \, dx $ = $ \int (x^2)(x^6 -2x^3 + 1) \, dx = \int (x^8 -2x^5 + x^2) \, dx$. The anti derivative of this becomes $ \frac{x^9}{9} - \frac{2x^6}{6} + \frac{x^3}{3} $.

However, these anti-derivatives are not equal. Through u-substitution, when $x=1$, the anti derivative evaluates to zero. In the second route, when I plug in $1$, I get $1/9$.

Where did I go wrong? From what I see, the $u$-substitution version is correct.

Comment: But the question is whether they differ by a constant.  Have you seen integral formulas that end with "+C"?

Comment: @GEdgar just beat me!

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial expansion:

\begin{align}
(x^3 - 1)^3 =&\ \binom{3}{0}(x^3)^3 + \binom{3}{1}(x^3)^2(-1) + \binom{3}{2}(x^3)^1(-1)^2 + \binom{3}{3}(-1)^3\\
=&\ x^9 - 3x^6 + 3x^3 - 1
\end{align}

Therefore:

$$
\frac{1}{3}\frac{(x^3 - 1)^3}{3} = \frac{x^9}{9} - \frac{x^6}{3} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{1}{9}
$$

Which is the same as what you got but the constant at the end is different (differs by an additive constant factor).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\underbrace{\frac{x^9}{9} - \frac{2x^6}{6} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \text{a constant}} = \underbrace{ \frac 1 3\cdot \frac{(x^3-1)^3} 3 + \text{a different constant}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, the question is what is the function at the point (1,0). And the constant will change if I use the first equation v. the second. So the first equation will have a constant of 0, which has a solution function of $ \frac {1}{3} * \frac {(x^3-1)^3}{3}$ with its constant = 0.

And the second way  $ \frac{x^9}{9} - \frac{2x^6}{6} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{1}{9} $ where 1/9 is my constant. I assume now the two functions are equal.

Comment: So, the problem statement you have provided here is incomplete.  Since you don't like our answers, maybe you should ask your instructor.